# What method should be used to tag specific texts, when the dataset is too small for training a model?

Tags: python, keras, nlp, unsupervised-learning

My problem is the following:

The task is to use a Machine Learning Algorithm to perform tagging on texts. This would be simple enough if those texts were about common topics where large datasets for training are readily available.

But these texts describe company KPI's and Products. The tagging should improve search inside the upcoming Data Catalog.

What complicates the matter: the amount of already human-tagged texts is very small (around 50)

So I was searching for a method to train a model on a dataset that has nothing to do with our dataset since it is highly specialized.
Is there a way to adapt pre-trained text classifiers to our data?

I'm fairly new to NLP/Machine Learning since I recently started studying this field. I mainly program in Python. If a solution in Python is available, it would be great!

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Sounds like a perfect recipe for "garbage in, garbage out".

Comment: Sounds impossible? You can look at few-shot or zero-shot classification methods, but they're designed to work for common categories, not specialized ones.